# Having trouble with void method

Tags: c#

I'm working on a program that has a cube class and a sphere class the program will find the volume, surface area,and size of the shape.

Here is my class for the cube:

```
class Cube
{ 
    private double _size;

    public double Size 
    { 
        get { return _size; }
        set
        {
            if (value >= 0)
            {
                _size = value;
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("size cannot be negative");
            }
        }
    }

    public double Volume
    {
        get { return Math.Pow(Size, 3); }
    }

    public double SurfaceArea
    {
        get { return  6 * Math.Pow(Size, 2); }
    }

    public Cube(double cubeSize)
    {
        Size = cubeSize;
    }

    public Cube()
    {
        Size = 1;
    }
}
```

I created a void method which is supposed to multiply my size class by 10% with a button:

```
public void Enlarge()
{
    Size * 0.1;
}
```

But I'm getting an error of operand cannot be applied to type "Size" and "double" and only assignment, call, increment.. etc can be used as an expression. I'm using C#

Comment: `Size * 0.1` what do you want to do with the result of that calculation?

Comment: It looks like you've defined a `Size` type somewhere (or there's a `using` directive importing such a type) because this otherwise looks like it should be giving you an error about how only method call, assignment, and increment/decrement expressions are valid statements. That message would've suggested that you're missing an assignment somewhere.

Comment: Also, how is that method magically supposed to know that you're referring to the `Size` property of a `Cube`? At the moment, you're referring to the `Size` property of the form that code is in.

Comment: It seems that it would make sense to have that method have a parameter of type `Cube` and then you change the `Size` of that object.

Comment: Re John's question, is `Enlarge` part of your `Cube` class or not? Your post is unclear on that because the way you've posted it is fragmented. There's no `class` keyword here.

Comment: Sorry yes enlarge is part of my cube class and I’m using a void method which is why there aren’t any parameters

Comment: *"using a void method which is why there aren’t any parameters"* - That's doesn't follow at all, as those are unrelated matters.

Comment: Rewrite your question so that you show the class in its complete form. Someone looking at this for the first time shouldn't have to read the comments to get the full picture.

Answer (score 1):

Please assign it to Size.

```
Size = Size * 0.1;
```